# Allow spaces between emails in regex

Tags: java, regex, email

I'm validating email for example "email1@domain.com" with this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$
```

Now I need to validate emails with spaces to allow multiple emails for example: "email1@domain.com email2@domain.com email3@domain.com email4@domain.com"

Any improve or help to do that?.
This is for Java.
Nota: I need a regex due to I'm using JSON SCHEMA validation to validate fields of JSON, I can't validate email per email.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7}$
```

Comment: Why don't you split the string using a space character as the delimiter and then validate each one at a time?

Comment: hi Ahmed.I can't split because im using JSON SCHEMA validation. I send a JSON to my api and validate fields per jsonshcema, in the shcema of email i configure a pattern. i can't split the string.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way would be to replace `^` with `(?:^|[ ])` and `$` with `(?=$|[ ])` and then put your original pattern in a capturing group if you want to "capture" the emails, not just validate them (i.e., `(?:^|[ ])(YourOriginalPatter)(?=$|[ ])`).

Here's an example using your pattern:

```
(?:^|[ ])([a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7})(?=$|[ ])
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uvNjtj/1)**.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be, u just repeat the complete pattern with a capturing group

```regex
^(([wW]{3}.)*[a-zA-Z0-9_+&*-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,7} *){1,}$
```